# Ilustrator CC Ubuntu 19.04 GUI is glitchy,rest of the program works pretty fine

Tags: graphics, gui, amd-graphics, 19.04, playonlinux

Well guys,stay with me on this one!

A noob figuring out how to linux 101,trying to get illustratorCC to work

I downloaded the .exe files (and the other files needed to install the program),installed PlayOnLinux,then followed what the program itself told me to do,dont let the program run after finishing,dont reboot etc.

So,the program runs with this error
[Unknown Error {CANT}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN1o5.png)
but it continues runing fine,except it is just a little bit glitchy(the text is kinda unclear to the eye)["The blurry text screenshot"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbIGu.png).
then the program absolutely looses it's sh*t when it starts [The program is all glitched out,looks like someone took a brush and smudged it to the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDhBM.png)

Now the actuall script runs fine,e.g if i Click Files>Exit,it runs fine,the script runs and exits the program,the problem here is that the GUI is unusable,which is a big deal when working with a GRAPHICAL DESIGN program...

POL sometimes detects that the program has "crashed" when exiting,so i copied the log file

POL Illustrator debug file:

> https://pastebin.com/3Pjdkgdx

Info about my Laptop:

> https://pastebin.com/iYDw8sFm

Grep for my GPU:

> VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics] (rev ea)

As i said,forgive my stupidity,still a noob,and if you need anything else for info,tell me!

TIA

Comment: You might want to see:  https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=37977

Comment: Thank you,will look into it i will try installing the `vcrun2015 runtime`,and updating the post